# How to Remove Space Around ReportViewer Control When in PrintLayout Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Is there a way the space from around the ReportViewer control can be removed when in PrintLayout mode? I want to maximize the size of the report viewer display area to improve readability. The form that has the control has been made as large as practical. The requirement is to see entire page in the viewer. Finding a way to remove this empty space from around the control makes it sufficiently large.

In the form constructor, there is:

```
    MyReportViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
```

When I change it to normal mode, there is no longer empty space around the control (but want aspects of print layout such as pagination functionality in the viewer).

```
    MyReportViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Normal);
```

Report viewer control displayed sizes in both modes as follows:
Print Layout Mode = 654x795 (size reduced by 16 or 17 pixels each side)
Normal Mode = 688x827
The report viewer is contained within a panel. I can see the panel background color for those 17 left/right and 16 top/bottom pixels when the mode is set to Print Layout.

Just let me know if additional information is needed.

Thanks!